# warning: control reaches end of non-void function In User-Defined Function

Tags: c, return, compiler-warnings

I'm afraid this is most likely just a good old-fashioned missed character, but I'm stumped.  Anyone else up for a parentheses hunt?  :)  I get the compiler error in the title with the following function.  Help?  Thanks in advance!

```
int print(char* cmd2, int sockfd)
{
    int cmdNum;
    int n;
    int numR;
    int i;

    SREC* record;

    if(strcmp(cmd2, "lname") == 0)
    {
        cmdNum = 1;
    }
    else if(strcmp(cmd2, "fname") == 0)
    {
        cmdNum = 2;
    }
    else if(strcmp(cmd2, "SID") == 0)
    {
        cmdNum = 3;
    }
    else if(strcmp(cmd2, "GPA") == 0)
    {
        cmdNum = 4;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Unrecognized list: %s\n\n", cmd2);
        return 1;
    }

    /*send cmdNum to server*/
    n = write(sockfd, &cmdNum, sizeof(int));
    if (n < 0)
    { 
        printf("ERROR writing to socket/n");
    }   

    /*recieve numR from server*/
    n = read(sockfd, &numR, 255);
    if (n < 0) 
    {
        printf("ERROR reading from socket\n");
    }

    printf("| SID   | Lname     | Fname      | M | GPA  |\n+-------+-----------+------------+---+------+");

    for(i = 0; i < numR; i++)
    {
        /*send i to server to tell it position of repetition*/
        n = write(sockfd, &i, sizeof(int));

        /*receive ith record*/
        n = read(sockfd, record, sizeof(SREC));

        /*print record to screen*/
        printf("| %05lu | %9s | %9s | %c | %.2f |", record->SID, record->lname, record->fname, record->initial, record->GPA);               }

        printf("+-------+-----------+------------+---+------+\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How about commenting all lines, and start uncommenting line by line until you find the problem?

Comment: You need a better editor if this caused you trouble.

Comment: If you use vim, the `%` command jumps to a matching parenthesis, bracket, or brace. Other editors probably have similar commands. Running the code through a formatter would also have found the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your line:

```
printf("| %05lu | %9s | %9s | %c | %.2f |", record->SID, record->lname, record->fname, record->initial, record->GPA);               }
```

There is a `}` at the end. Scroll all the way to the right.

Comment: +1 Eagle eyes. :) I didn't see that until I saw your reply.

Comment: You freaking rock sir.  Eagle eyes indeed! :)  Thanks.